# Perform a find operation of class name with jquery data element

Tags: jquery, find, custom-data-attribute

I have the following piece of HTML code defined inside a jQuery element:

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee" data-price_modifier="0.50" data-product_modifier="αγγουράκια έξτρα">αγγουράκια έξτρα<br class="ui-selectee"> €0.50</li><li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee ui-selected" data-price_modifier="1.00" data-product_modifier="Nτοματίνια τορφαντά">Nτοματίνια τορφαντά<br class="ui-selectee"> €1.00</li>
```

the above piece of code is set dynamically inside the following element:

```
var productAdded = $('<tr class="product" data-real_id = "'+ id +'" data-id_modal="'+ mod_id +'"><td class="product_name2"><button href="#0" class="button2" style="background-color:#00a65a;" data-comment=""  data-modifiers="" data-span_mod = "" data-real_id = "'+ id +'" data-id_modall="'+ mod_id +'" id = "'+ comment_id +'">' + product_name + '</button></td><td class="quantity"><span class="select"><select id="cd-product-'+ id +'" name="quantity"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option></select></span></td><td class="price">' + product_price + '</td><td><a href="#0" class="delete-item"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td></tr>');
```

The data attribute: "data-modifiers" holds the first listed html code.

How can I perform a find operation inside the data attribute so as to extract all classes which contain the class name ".ui-selected" ?

Comment: At least format the code so that we can read it. Don't put every thing in single line

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - Your question is not clear

Comment: sorry i thought this was done automatically through the "code" option of the text editor.

Comment: If the code is in one line then the editor shows it in one line too

Comment: ok thanks for the advice